# Joomla 1 to Joomla 3. copy DB content (only xxxxx_content table in DB)

Tags: mysql, database, joomla3.0

I have to migrate the content (only articles, not categories.) from Joomla 1.0.18 to Joomla 3.7.5.

Because there is no tool to accomplish this I decided to transfer the xxxxx_content table (from J! 1.0) with PHPmyADMIN to J! 3 xxxx_content table.

I saw the columns in the Joomla 1 are similar to columns in Joomla 3 - hovewer there are some differences which I can handle ...

**But there is only column that puzzles me! That is the column asset_id (FK to the #_assets table) column which is not present in Joomla 1.**

In Joomla 3 it is related to table xxxxx_assets and I have no idea what is for and how it works.

I successfully imported the content from Joomla 1 db to Joomla 3 db.

Now all values in the assets_id column (table xxxxx_content) are 1 and I think this is the problem! My site isn't working properly ...

Hovewer I can see all articles in backend in Joomla 3 instalation.

So, my question is:

Can I reset or restore or repair data in column assets_id (table _content) and all table _assets in Joomla 3?

Thank you.

Best regards.

Answer (score 0):

Try using the ACL Manager extension.  It adds and repairs the assets table.  I use it on every site I build: https://www.aclmanager.net/

Comment: Thank you for your tip ... I will try it!